# When would you reuse a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am planning an app and trying to explore all the possible development options/methods I have available. One thing I'm struggling to get my head around is Fragments. I see a lot of people praising them as you can "resuse" fragments throughout the app but I can't think of an example situation.

From some example apps I have looked at (all been tabular layouts) the code for each fragment has one layout, so why not have a seperate activity instead?

I am hoping to implement a tabular layout in my app. If anyone can give me an example of a fragment being reused within an app I hope it will give me a better understanding of the benefits.

Comment: `Fragments` are useful because you can design one part of your layout, and reuse it somewhere else - think of GMail, on a tablet you have a list of your emails on the left and content on the right and on a smartphone you first pick an email and then go to a detail view with the contents. You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Aside from that you should always use `Fragments`, `Activities` are just supposed to be containers for `Fragments`. Implement your functionality in `Fragments` and use `Activities` just to display them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Reuse" is overrated. Of course - you can put this same fragment (with this same features) in different places of your application - let's say that you can use a fragment in different, horizontal and vertical layouts (as you probably saw in Google's tutorial).

But at the end using fragments simplifies your project - for example - you can switch fragments inside one activity and get benefits of much easier navigation and in app communication.

Using fragments gives you one more thing - flexibility. It's much easier to move some view from one place to another, or just remove from application. All that because fragment encapsulates logic and usually a view, still offering power of externally managed lifecycle.
(Thanks for comment from Richard Le Mesurier)

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment` is not a `View` neither a `ViewGroup`. It is not a visual element at all. `Fragment` inherits directly from `Object`.

One should think of a `Fragment` as a unity of a reusable code, reusable in various `Activities` (the `Activities` consist of visible elements).

Thus if you can think of any code you can reuse through several `Activities` (even the same `Activity` with different layout) and that code somehow depends on `Activity` lifecycle, then you probably should make this code a `Fragment`.